# Is it possible to override a class inside glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish

I have written a soap client application running on glassfish server.

For soap security reason I had to update a class (SecurityHeather.java) part of Metro project which is provided through webservices-osgi.jar glassfish's module.

Is there anyway to override the class inside the glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar ?

The easiest way is to update the class inside the jar file and save it. but im not sure its the best way or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching through a lot of similar posts and reading through tons of glassfish docs I was able to find out the solution for this problem. There is a glassfish-web.xml deployment descriptor which defines the element class-loader. By default the classloader delegates all the class loading functionality to its parent classloader which looks for the jars in the modules folder of glassfish installation directory. If we set the delegate attribute of the class-loader element to false, the delegation model is inverted and the child classloader does the class loading, loading the classes available in the war libraries first and then looking at glassfish modules folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish 
 Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/SampleApp</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="false"/>
 <jsp-config>
   <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
     <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.
     </description>
     </property>
   </jsp-config>
  </glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Note, this does not work for all packages. From the glassfish documentation: For a number of packages, including java.* and javax.*, symbol resolution is always delegated to the parent class loader regardless of the delegate setting. This prevents applications from overriding core Java runtime classes or changing the API versions of specifications that are part of the Java EE platform.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible. I just copy the class inside the jar file. and restarted the server

However I made it automatically override the class with maven.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webservices-osgi</artifactId>
                                <version>${original.webservices-osgi.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <excludes>
                                    **/SecurityHeader*.class
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Research JRebel or DCEVM + Hotswap